# Trying to get perimeters to change depending on the URL with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get my text color to change depending on the URL of my Localhost. First I need to get this "Hello" to display, where am I going wrong?

```
var http = require('http');

var PORT = 80;

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.end('<p>Hello World</p><p>Path requested: ' + request.url + '</p>');
})

server.listen(PORT,function(){
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + PORT)
});

server.get('/blue', function(request, response) {
    response.end('<p>Hello</p>');
});
```

Comment: There is no `get()` method for the `httpServer` class.  You should look into express for effective routing capabilities.

Comment: Oh right, I'm just trying to get this small function to work, without using any other frameworks then Node. Could you recommend how to do this?

Comment: Definitely agree with @ThomasStringer.  A framework like Express will make your life a lot easier if you plan to do any more than just this basic example.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, instead of...

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.end('<p>Hello World</p><p>Path requested: ' + request.url + '</p>');
})
```

...in order to handle routes, try...

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    var color = 'black';
    if (request.url === '/blue') {
        color = 'blue';
    } else if (request.url === '/red') {
        color = 'red';
    }
    response.end('<p style="color:' + color + ';">Hello World</p><p>Path requested: ' + request.url + '</p>');
})
```

**Second**, you'll have to get rid of the the `server.get` call because Node doesn't provide that kind of routing out of the box.

Comment: Wow thanks! got it :) I tried something similar my first time around but I must have messed up somewhere. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to parse the request URL:

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url.toLowerCase() === '/blue' || req.url.toLowerCase() === '/blue/') {
        res.end('<p style="color: blue">you put the color blue</p>');
    }
    else {
        res.end('<p>you did not put blue</p>');
    }
});
```

Without using middleware (like [express js](http://expressjs.com/), which is awesome), you'll have to work with the HTTP request to parse and consume to take action based of the nature of the request.

*Note: I **highly** recommend express, it makes so many HTTP things quite a bit easier*